# Kotlin data class to deserialize JSON list of objects

Tags: android, json, kotlin, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a retrofit request that returns the JSON object below. The JSON is a list of objects starting with stock ticker name which is dynamic (could be AAPL/GOOG/MSFT...etc).

How can i create a kotlin data class to de-serialize this JSON?

Note i do not want to hardcode AAPL/GOOG etc but rather have a dynamic data class that can be used based on the ticker name and whether pulling 3,4,5 tickers or more. I would also like to avoid using Gson or other third party libraries.

```
{
  "AAPL": {
    "meta": {
      "symbol": "AAPL",
      "interval": "1min",
      "currency": "USD",
      "exchange_timezone": "America/New_York",
      "exchange": "NASDAQ",
      "type": "Common Stock"
    },
    "values": [
      {
        "datetime": "2021-12-31 15:59:00",
        "open": "177.61000",
        "high": "177.75000",
        "low": "177.55000",
        "close": "177.59000",
        "volume": "1536914"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "2021-12-31 15:58:00",
        "open": "177.56000",
        "high": "177.67999",
        "low": "177.49001",
        "close": "177.61000",
        "volume": "650356"
      }
    ],
    "status": "ok"
  },
  "GOOG": {
    "meta": {
      "symbol": "GOOG",
      "interval": "1min",
      "currency": "USD",
      "exchange_timezone": "America/New_York",
      "exchange": "NASDAQ",
      "type": "Common Stock"
    },
    "values": [
      {
        "datetime": "2021-12-31 15:59:00",
        "open": "2895.86011",
        "high": "2897.14990",
        "low": "2893.55005",
        "close": "2893.58008",
        "volume": "47979"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "2021-12-31 15:58:00",
        "open": "2895.70996",
        "high": "2896.87012",
        "low": "2895.40991",
        "close": "2896.36255",
        "volume": "21948"
      }
    ],
    "status": "ok"
  },
  "MSFT": {
    "meta": {
      "symbol": "MSFT",
      "interval": "1min",
      "currency": "USD",
      "exchange_timezone": "America/New_York",
      "exchange": "NASDAQ",
      "type": "Common Stock"
    },
    "values": [
      {
        "datetime": "2021-12-31 15:59:00",
        "open": "336.39001",
        "high": "336.54001",
        "low": "336.10999",
        "close": "336.20999",
        "volume": "472414"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "2021-12-31 15:58:00",
        "open": "336.59000",
        "high": "336.67999",
        "low": "336.39001",
        "close": "336.39001",
        "volume": "155067"
      }
    ],
    "status": "ok"
  }
}
```

> Blockquote

```
data class Ticker (

    /*????How to handle list of objects with dynamic ticker names here????*/
    var Meta: Meta,
    var values: List<Values>,
    var status: String

)

data class Meta(

    var symbol: String,
    var interval: String,
    var currency: String,
    var currencyQuote: String,
    var exchange: String,
    var exchangeTimezone: String,
    var type: String,

    )

data class Values (

    var datetime: String,
    var open: String,
    var high: String,
    var low: String,
    var close: String,
    var volume: String

)
```

Answer (score 1):

The payload you have provided is not a list, it's a `Map<String, Ticker>`.

Comment: thanks @Mafor, are you saying that the native de-serialized version of this JSON is a Map?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "native deserialization version". Technically, the JSON you've provided is a json object, and as such, it can be deserialized either to a concrete class, with hardcoded field names, or to a map, but not to a list.